# Manipulating fillable PDFs in Elixir/Erlang

Tags: pdf, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, pdf-manipulation

I've been trying to find example functionality in Elixir or Erlang for taking a fillable PDF and then filling it with input data from an application.

So far I haven't been able to find any solutions to this in either Elixir or Erlang.

Does anyone know of a good method or module we could use in order to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't forget you can always shell out to execute commands too.

Answer (score 4):

I am using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html) to generate pdf file from html,markdown,doc,epub... format. It is an haskell program, that relies on miktex, mactex or texlive for pdf generation, it executes all conversion via a command line that can be easily generated by any program.